# I am unable to login to the SDL Web content manager?

Tags: web8, installation

I have copied existing content management DB and ran upgrade scripts.
Once SDL Web 8 Installation is completed, configured Directory services and restarted the system, I am unable to login using the MTS user provided in the instillation wizard.Did I miss any steps, How can I connect to the CM explorer?

Comment: Did you check the logs (cm and core) ? Is there any indication ? You need to share more information here.

Comment: If you copied the database, chances are that the old MTSUser is still the one in the trustees table. Change it to match the new one

Comment: To avoid the conflicts we used name DMTSUser for MTS user. I am getting the below error while trying to connect the CMS System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.CoreServiceFault]: Access is denied for the user 56785-TRIDTEST\DMTSUser. (Fault Detail is equal to Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.CoreServiceFault).

Comment: Make sure you replace existing TRIDTEST\MTSUser with TRIDTEST\DMTSUser in TRUSTEES table in your CM database and try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Followed Nuno and ARRX suggestion and update the Trustee table,Content Management Explorer allowed me to login.Thank you for suggestion.

Once followed the suggestions I am able to login to explorer where as I am unable to see Content, Once I enabled Anonymous authentication in IIS as per SDL support suggestion I am able to see content and publications.

Comment: In principle, even for a small database hack like this, you should first get approval from support so that they can be sure you won't accidentally harm your system. In future though, it's probably best to add the trustee before you copy the database.

Comment: While I updated Anonymous authentication in IIS, I Enabled same for Topology Manager also due to that I am unable to delete the publication.As per Support suggestion I enable Windows Authentication for Topology Manager resolved my issue. @Dominic when you say "add the trustee before you copy the database" where should I add the user in Database, I was expecting that what ever information we are providing in wizard will save the user and grant me access to the system

Comment: I meant that if you have a database in, say, your production environment that you are going to export and then import to development, before you do this, go in to the user interface and add the user that you will need in development. If the user is in a different domain, you might need to use a GUI extension or a script to do this, but the principle is the same.